# Transpose data from two columns to rows for every 10th observation in the second row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose

I have data where the first column is metadata attributes, and the second column are values of each attribute. There are 10 metadata attributes, and 1000's of observations (each having just those 10 attritubes). What I want to do is transpose this data so that the 10 metadta attributes are columns, and the observations of each attribute are the rows. I know this sounds simple but I cannot figure out how to do this simply

| Metadata | Observations |
| --- | --- |
| M1 | 1-1 |
| M2 | 1-2 |
| M3 | 1-3 |
| M4 | 1-4 |
| M5 | 1-5 |
| M6 | 1-6 |
| M7 | 1-7 |
| M8 | 1-8 |
| M9 | 1-9 |
| M10 | 1-10 |
| M1 | 2-1 |
| M2 | 2-2 |
| M3 | 2-3 |
| ... | ... |

I want to transpose the data so that the metadata in column 1 are the header names and the observations in column two are rows

| M1 | M2 | M3 | M4 | M5 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1 | 1-2 | 1-3 | 1-4 | 1-5 | ... |
| 2-1 | 2-2 | 2-3 | 2-4 | 2-5 | ... |

In Excel I can do something like ...

```
=TRANSPOSE(A1:A10)
=TRANSPOSE(B1:B10)
=TRANSPOSE(B11:B20)
...
```

But there has to be a simpler way to transpose observations in column b

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
=LET(A,A2:A21, B,B2:B21, ux,UNIQUE(A), 
 wrap,WRAPROWS(B,10),VSTACK(TOROW(ux),wrap))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]
In case you have less than `10` values in some rows, and you would like to pad missing cells with some value, for example empty string, you can use the third input argument of `WRAPROWS`.

Answer (score 1):

This formula does not care how may metadata are available.  It is is dynamic and will increase or decrease the number of columns depending on the unique list of metadata.

It also is not dependent on sort order.

```
=LET(
    fclm,A2:A14,
    sclm,B2:B14,
    lbl,UNIQUE(fclm),
    MAKEARRAY(
        MAX(BYROW(lbl,LAMBDA(z,COUNTA(FILTER(fclm,fclm=z)))))+1,
        ROWS(lbl),
        LAMBDA(y,x,IF(y=1,INDEX(lbl,x),IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(sclm,fclm=INDEX(lbl,x)),y-1),"")))))
```

[image]

unsorted:

[image]

M10 removed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `=TRANSPOSE(A2:A11)` to get headers and `=WRAPROWS(B2:B26,10,"")` to transpose `B` column:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

[image]

---

```
=VSTACK(TOROW(UNIQUE(A2:A14)),WRAPROWS(B2:B14,10,""))
```

---

Not sure about your Excel Version, but if you are in `MS365` the one above will work if not try the one in below:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D10` --> **Fill Right**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$14,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C10:C10,$A$2:$A$14),0)),"")
```

---

• Formula used in cell `D11` --> **Fill Down & Fill Right**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$14,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW($B$2:$B$14)-ROW($B$2)+1)/(D$10=$A$2:$A$14),ROW(A1))),"")
```

---

**Note:** You may need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode if you are not an `MS365` user and using the second formula alternative.

---

Another way, using `LET()` and defining a variable for the whole data as `x`

[image]

---

```
=LET(x,A2:B14,
y,TOROW(UNIQUE(INDEX(x,,1))),
z,WRAPROWS(INDEX(x,,2),10,""),
VSTACK(y,z))
```

---

Comment: it looks like you didn't look at my answer before, we had the same idea. Regards.

Comment: Oh yes, same idea absolutely, also its a common solutionx